# Multiple appendChild calls don't work

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I read through several threads without find a clear answer.
I'm using a JavaScript library (Drinks.js) to put several widgets on my webpage.
The following code will add one single item to my div element `pnlThermo`:

```
function create(item) { 
    var thermo = Drinks.createElement('display');
    thermo.setAttribute('id', item);
    thermo.setAttribute('label', item);
    Drinks.appendChild('pnlThermo', thermo);         
}
```

Well, now I want to add several items to the same div element. No matter if I use a for cycle or call the function explicitly only the first item will be rendered. For example:

```
create('T1');
create('T2');
create('T3');
```

leads to show `T1` only.
Perhaps I missed something, I'm quite new to JavaScript programming.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Does the HTML element `<display>` exists?

Comment: I think you are using same ID each time?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Nope cause the ID's is `T1, T2, T3`

Comment: `Drinks.js` doesn't appear to be a very common library and I can't find anything via Google that I'm confident is what you are talking about. A link to it would be useful.

Comment: @NULL — I'm not sure `<display>` is supposed to be an HTML element, `createElement` is being called on `Drinks` not `document`.

Comment: For anyone interested the Drinks.js reference manual is here : http://goincompany.com/DTManual01.pdf

Comment: well, I managed to work changing a bit the appendChild statement. Here the working solution:

    var dest = document.getElementById('pnlThermo');
    // .. the code above
    dest.appendChild(thermo);

but the Drinks.js guide suggests the previous method which doesn't work for me. Now I can create how many item I want (I don't know how to put them side by side instead of one below other, but this is another question).
Yes, display is the HTML element provided by the Drinks.js library.

Comment: Ok, it will better to use the span tag if I want to place them side by side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference manual ( http://goincompany.com/DTManual01.pdf ) says :

> After you have created the HTML element, you have to append it to an
>   HTML container. In order to do this you have to use the appendChild
>   function, provided by the Drinks class. Drinks.appendChild('body',
>   gauge); 'body' is the id of the HTML container. If the parent is an
>   instrument, this function doesn't work. We have to use the appendChild
>   method of the instrument, but we'll see this later.

Seems to imply that the first parameter needs to be an HTML tagname, which makes little sense
but then the library is a little wierd IMHO.

Comment: Yep, I forgot to mention that pnlThermo is a standard div element: <div id="pnlThermo"></div>

Comment: The problem is that the multiple appendChild functions don't work if called within the onLoad event of the body tag. For example:

    <body onLoad="initBoard();">
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <script>
        create('T1');
        create('T2');
    </script>

doesn't work. Instead:

    <input type="button" onclick="initBoard();" value="click"/> 

works fine.
I cannot understand if the issue is related to the Drinks.js code or to a general javascript programming.

Comment: In your non working scenario, InitBoard is not called till AFTER the creates. In your second, the revere is true. I normally do not use onLoad but put all my JS scripts after the body tag and before the HTML tag so that the order of execution is perfectly clear.

Comment: Oh well. Even with your last hint it didn't work. The solution is: call the initBoard with some delay, using setTimeout("initBoard()", 50);. Now works like a charm... I don't know why, though.